# React-native import path shortcuts issues

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have a a RN app (RN version 0.48.3), my folder structure:

```
/index.ios.js
/index.android.js
/app/index.js
```

index.ios.js:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import home from './app';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('home', () => home);
```

/app/index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
  ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If i run the app, it shows me this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for Built-in components)
>   or a class/Object...

But when a change the second line in index.ios.js it works correctly:

```
import home from './app'; -> import home from './app/index.js';
```

Anyone can explain to me why? The path "./app" is not correct with index.js inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try With Home with camelcase, and remove home from you class name

voila :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
  ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}



 import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import Home from './app';
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('Home', () => Home);
```

Comment: Same error...  it work only if i change the path with import Home from './app/index.js'; its not a problem but i want to know why...

Comment: my solution work ? 
when you put ./app you leave a node to take the annomye element that is in the module.export object, in your case you have specified a name while an export default does not need a name , if you want to do what you did. here an example: {Home} and export class Home ...

Comment: Thanks, but i have the same error with your solution, it seems that can not get the path "./app" but only with "./app/index.js" it work...